# Open Facebook i safari if the Facebook native app is not installed

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, safari, native

I'm making an application where i would open Facebook native app from within the app.
That problem i have sold with this

```
 NSString* urlString = @"fb://groups/";
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
```

But if the native app isn't installed it should open Facebook in the native safari app on the iPhone. That is my problem?

Is there anyone that could help me with that?

Answer (score 7):

```
NSString fbURL = @"fb://group/5385407511";
BOOL canOpenURL = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fbURL]];

if(canOpenURL) {
    [[UIApplication openURL:[NSURL urlWithString:fbURL]];
} else {
    [[UIApplication openURL:@"http://facebook.com"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad idea to write your app in a way which relies on Facebook's native app not changing its internal structure, your app could break at any moment.

That said, if you must do this for some reason, you can check if the Facebook app is installed by checking an `fb://` URL with UIApplication's

```
- (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```